# Facebook API Get Ad Account Ad Spend

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I'm attempting to just get the spend for specific Ad Accounts from the previous day. Whenever I send up the request:

```
    $api = Api::instance();



    $account = new AdAccount('act_<account_id>');

    $params = array(
      'level' => 'account',
      'date_preset' => 'yesterday',
      'fields' => ['spend', 'account_id'],

    );
    $insights = $account->getInsights(array(), $params);

    print_r($insights);
```

I get a large protected object back and can't seem to find any documentation as to how to access the actual requested data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
            //Get HLG Ad Spend
        $account = new AdAccount('act_10153795481711178');

        $params = array(
          'level' => 'account',
          'date_preset' => 'yesterday',
          'fields' => ['spend', 'account_id']

        );
        $insights = $account->getInsights(array(), $params);

        $hlgData = $insights->getResponse()->getContent()['data'];
        if(isset($hlgData[0]))
        {
              $hlgSpendFB = $hlgData[0]['spend'];
        }else{
             $hlgSpendFB = "0";
        }
```

Above is how I was able to get the data from the Ad Account for spend from previous day. After digging through the object itself I was able to find the getter functions that procured the data requested.

Comment: FYI, This is the same for the [javascript SDK](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-nodejs-business-sdk/blob/master/src/objects/ad-account.js#L1027): `account.getInsights([], {level: 'account', date_preset: 'yesterday', fields: [....]}).then(...)`